# How to refresh data in other components (Angular 7, router.navigate) when navigating from one to another?

Tags: html, web-services, data-binding, bootstrap-4, angular7

I am new to front-end dev, application is in Angular 7

My homepage contains list of items, clicking on each item will redirect to another page. While navigating I want the title bar (third component) to update with respect to the item which I clicked. Right now it only updates if I manually reload the page

I am using router for navigation

```
 router.navigate([route]);
```

.......EDIT.............

I have tried the following link....

https://medium.com/@rakshitshah/refresh-angular-component-without-navigation-148a87c2de3f

but it is throwing error - Object is unsubscribed,

Also tried activatedrouter instead of Router

Comment: you must use route as an observable rather than the activated route snapshot

Comment: thanks, could you please tell me lil bit more on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577118/why-activatedroute-in-angular-router-params-is-observable

Comment: Thanks for the link @DhananjaiPai, this seems solution for the Routerlink , but I am looking to update span element. My link works fine and I am able to navigate to second component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to update the title with this

```
  function updateDiv()
{ 
$( "#here" ).load(window.location.href + " #here" ); 
}
```

you can change #here(id) for .class(class) which you ill set on that title.it should update that part of a page without reloading

Comment: Hi @Marek Langer, is it possible without jquery?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure, I use it bcs of other things anyway use this:   `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I solved it without using function, just added window.location.href = <route> after navigate method.

Answer (score 0):

I refreshed the page after navigation. The navigation method is in router.

```
router.navigate([next]);
window.location.href = 'next';
```

next(string) is the path-  where you want the current page to navigate.